# iPhone's 3G usage counter

Tags: iphone

Maybe this is silly but...

How can I find out the 3G usage on my iPhone 4? (like a counter telling how many Mbytes I have been moving over the 3G network)

Answer (score 1):

3G data usage is listed in the General Application under Usage.

But you can also download [AT&T's app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/at-t-mywireless-mobile/id309172177?mt=8) or [Vodafone's app](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/my-vodafone/id370901726?mt=8) to check it from their perspective as well.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. Now I need to monthly reset the statistics. So I need an app for that...I'll check with my carrier (Vodafone) like you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Michael pointed out you can use the usage stats in Settings to find this out although I would be surprised if your carrier doesn't provide you with this information.

What network are you on? Most of them even have apps which tell you your call/text/data limits when logged in (or at least they do here in the UK).

Comment: I'm on Vodafone. They probably do have this info somewhere....

Comment: Try logging onto your mobile account or searching the appstore for MyVodaphone. I haven't used it myself but it's there...